# How to recover a VB project (before decompiling)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I don't manage to open anymore my Visual Basic project. Apparently, there are files missing, but I don't think I deleted some files since the last use.

My project is here : C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Predi

In this folder, there is thus a second folder Predi, which contains the folders obj, bin, My Project and the VB files.

(Remark : My "Main Form" has the same name than my project. Perhaps it's the reason of the problem ?)

When I open the project, I get the 3 following errors :

- unable to open module file 'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Predi.Designer.vb' : The system cannot find the file specified.
- unable to open module file 'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Predi.vb' : The system cannot find the file specified.
- 'Predi' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication1'.

Firstly, I don't get why Visual Studio is looking for the files in "Documents" folder ?

Secondly, in the folder Predi, the files Predi.Designer.vb and Predi.vb are present, but they corresponds to a very old version (I think from the date of creation).

Finally, my project is thus not compiling anymore. (but I can run the last successful build).

As Iam new with VB, perhaps I just missed something ??

In addition I saved the project in my dropbox, but the same problem is happening (looking for files).

I also opened the binary file Predi.pdb in the folder bin/Debug. It contains some ascii characters which corresponds to the last version of my code ! So, it should be possible to recover the code from this file, isn'it ?

I would like to try everything before using the decompiling... :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check the vbproj file (edit it, it is just XML) and try manually fixing the (relative) paths to the files.

Comment: Try to remove the Predi form from your Solution in VS and add an existing item => add the Predi item again. You probably have relative path errors like Styxxy suggests

Comment: Thanks for your help !
It works when I do that, but the problem is, as I wrote :
the files Predi.Designer.vb and Predi.vb which are present in the folder Projects\Predi\Predi corresponds to the first version of my code. If i run that, I loose everything.
So, I don't understand where are the last version of Predi.vb, or it is only in the pdb file or I don't know...

Comment: The reason of my problem is maybe that I renamed my main form, from "Form1" to "Predi" (the same name than the project) ?